# Execute in php .sh file

Tags: php, exec, rsync

i am trying to execute in php one .sh file

this file is located in /home/update.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/rsync -zaP '-e ssh -i /home/id_rsa_ws -v -p 6633' --del /var/www root@xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/
```

execute this file working well:

```
cd /home/; ./update.sh;
```

**the Problem is: i need to execute this file in php**

What i already tried in php:

1 - nothing happens.

```
    $contents = file_get_contents('/home/distribute.sh');
    echo '<pre>';
    echo shell_exec($contents);
```

i tried also :

2.

```
    exec("cd /home/;./update.sh 2>&1",$o,$return);
    print_r($o);
    print_r($return);

    Array
    (
            [0] => OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
            [1] => debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
            [2] => debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
            [3] => debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 6633.
            [4] => debug1: Connection established.
            [5] => debug1: identity file /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa_ws type 0
            [6] => debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
            [7] => debug1: identity file /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa_ws-cert type -1
            [8] => debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
            [9] => debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
            [10] => debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
            [11] => debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6633 as 'root'
            [12] => debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
            [13] => debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
            [14] => debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
            [15] => debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
            [16] => debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
            [17] => debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
            [18] => debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
            [19] => debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:VYnLDKxjyAr9Peqx/Ef03k+99009S6y3OZvRL5euGE8
            [20] => debug1: checking without port identifier
            [21] => debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
            [22] => Host key verification failed.
            [23] => rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
            [24] => rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]
    )
    255
```

here are the file in linux:

```
    cd /home/
    total 12K
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data root  111 Jul  7 12:20 update.sh
    -rw------- 1 www-data root 1.7K Jul  6 02:26 id_rsa_ws
    -rw------- 1 www-data root  393 Jul  6 02:26 id_rsa_ws.pub
```

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Is it `update.sh` or `distribute.sh`? And is `.ch` a typo for `.sh`?

Comment: yes, thx - changed text

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the command line in `exec()` so you'll get the error messages.

Comment: Barmar, thank you,  this , what i getting: Array
(
    [0] => Host key verification failed.
    [1] => rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
    [2] => rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.2]
)
255

Comment: So it's an SSH problem with the authentication key. Try using `ssh -v` so you get detailed logging.

Comment: It looks like the private key file is protected with a password, so SSH needs to prompt for a password. It can't do that when you run the script from the webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar]

after **Barmar** recommendation i changed following:

A. I moved ssh key to /var/www/.ssh

B. I changed command in .sh file, me add two parameters

```
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null


    /usr/bin/rsync -zaP '-e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa_ws -v -p 6633' --del /var/www root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/
```